# Enable etcd service auto start in CoreOS via systemd

Tags: docker, systemd, coreos, etcd

I have deployed a CoreOS standealone server with VMware image follow this [guide](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/vmware/) to experience CoreOS.

After deploy success, I found that my CoreOS only enable Docker service, without etcd and fleet service running.  Although I know how to use systemd to run etcd and fleet service manually.  And I also know use a proper cloud-config can install CoreOS in which etcd and fleet service start automatically.

But I want to know that:

1. Is it possible to place a unit file in `/etc/systemd/system` to make systemd starts etcd service automatically?
2. If can, what is the content of the unit file?
3. If cannot, what is the other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes. You must have a an etcd.service and fleet.service with an Install section. I've added WantedBy=default.target in mine.
2. They are already placed on coreos systems within /usr/lib64/systemd/system/. You can copy them to /etc/systemd/system/:

```
$ cp /usr/lib64/systemd/system/etcd.service /etc/systemd/system/
$ cp /usr/lib64/systemd/system/fleet.service /etc/systemd/system/
$ echo -e '[Install]\nWantedBy=default.target >> /etc/systemd/system/fleet.service
$ echo -e '[Install]\nWantedBy=default.target >> /etc/systemd/system/etcd.service
$ systemctl enable etcd.service
$ systemctl enable fleet.service
```

I'll also give you the general warning here that I have no idea what changes to /etc/systemd/ do in the long run, given CoreOSs upgrade system. An upgrade could wipe out /etc/systemd/ leaving you in a confused state as to what happened to your customized systemd scripts not managed by cloud-init.

Comment: While this will work, it's much better to follow best practices and use a cloud-config, particularly with CoreOS. And if you are using this in production, having a cloud-config to replicate these is very beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is with [cloud-config](https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cloudinit-cloud-config/). Specifically for VMware, you'll need to serve the cloud-config via [config-drive](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/vmware/#cloud-config) as documented.

It's kind of a pain, but it'll work.

Comment: Thanks. So is cloud-config the ONLY way to make services startup automatically?

Comment: Specifically, unit files are only way to start things automatically, but how you create them is up to you. You can provide them in your cloud-config under the units parameter. You can also place them on disk in /etc/systemd/system.